# The annotation @Configuration is disallowed for this location

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, configuration

While following the tutorial on [dzone](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-mvc-and-java-based-configuration-1) to make a simple spring+maven project, i am getting error message @Configuration is disallowed for this location.

My class -

```
package com.xyz;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example")
public class SpringConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {@Configuration
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Purpose of @Configuration annotation is to specify a class where spring will find Objects (@Bean)  to hold in spring context so that they are available through out the application.

To specify such class put @Configuration on the top of class declaration. Spring will automatically read @Bean methods to fetch and store bean objects.

Answer (score 0):

`@Configuration` is apply-able to element TYPE (class) only, so you can't not place that annotation in the middle of your code like that:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Component
public @interface Configuration
```